# mysqli function to store encrypted text

Tags: php, mysqli

I have gotten the below code to work and it seems fairly robust:  it works with different languages (UTF-8) and now I want to store the result in a database.  My problem is that I am only familiar with old, outdated mysql statements and would like to use mysqli. Can anyone point me to a simple yet secure function that will take input A and store it in a database...and then show me where in THIS code I need to add it?

```
<?php
/*
 * PHP 5.3.18 on windows XP
 *
 * I don't have open_ssl active from PHP so used MCRYPT_RAND for the salt.
 * It is adequate for this exercise.
 *
 * As the encoded SALT and encrypted output are binary code i have converted all
 * the output to Base64 encoding to ensure it is HTML safe.
 *
 * It selects the appropriate default action in the 'do' select list.
 *
 * There is a new 'salt' generated at each encryption and the user is prevented from
 * changing it by making the display field as 'readonly'. Normally this would be a 'hidden' field'.
 *
 */

$isEncrypted = null; // used to set default output options
                     // i like to pre-declare the script 'global' variables


$key_size = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);


if($_POST){ // we have some input...
$encryption_key = $_POST["key"];
$string = $_POST["msg"]; // this may be base64 encoded...


if($_POST["do"]=="encrypt"){
    $isEncrypted = true; // used to set defaults

    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,  MCRYPT_RAND); // new salt with each encryption
    $result = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $encryption_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
    $result = base64_encode($result); // $result is binary so encode as HTML safe.


}else{
    $isEncrypted = false; // used to set defaults

    $iv = base64_decode($_POST["iv"]); // get current salt converted back to binary format
    $string = base64_decode($string); // convert encoded text back to binary string
    $result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $encryption_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
}
}else{ // no input so create something useful...
  $isEncrypted = false; // used to set default actions

  $result = 'enter text to encrypt...'; // sample text
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,  MCRYPT_RAND); // new salt
  $encryption_key = substr('testing!' . uniqid() . '!testing', 0, $key_size);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test Encryption with base64 encoding.</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main" id="main">
    <!-- heading -->
    <strong><?php echo $isEncrypted ? 'Encrypted' : 'Decrypted'; ?></strong><br/>

    <form method="POST" action="">

        <!-- do not allow the user to change the salt by setting 'readonly' -->
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo base64_encode($iv); ?>" readonly name="iv"/> <br/>

        <!-- supply a suggested password but the user can change it -->
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $encryption_key; ?>" name="key"/><br/>

        <!-- either show the encoded text as HTML safe string -->
        <!--- or show as plain text -->
        <textarea name="msg" ><?php echo $result; ?></textarea><br/>

        <!-- set the appropriate action as the default -->
        <select name="do">
          <option <?php echo $isEncrypted ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>decrypt</option>
          <option <?php echo $isEncrypted ? '' : 'selected'; ?>>encrypt</option>
        </select><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="GO"/>
    </form>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On a different note, anyone know why this same code works fine on my server in the wild but when I cut and paste it into my local dev server it causes a white page?  It's NOT typos, I've carefully checked.  Anything in the configuration, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You will still be writing 'old' MySQL statements, because 'mysqli' is an *improved* driver (hence, the "i") to take advantage of features in MySQL >= 4.1. It is considered 'dual procedural and object-oriented API'. For instance, to connect to your MySQL DB, you could do [either of the following](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059):

```
// mysqli, procedural way
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database');

// mysqli, object oriented way
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database');
```

You should also look at the [PDO driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (PHP Data Objects), which provides a data access *abstraction layer* allowing your code to access many more DBMs besides and including MySQL.

Comment: I don't plan to use anything other than mysql, but if I ever do then PDO makes sense.  Right now I'm trying to learn which of these two methods makes sense.  Can I replace "mysql_connect" with "mysqli_connect" and all the others (ie mysql_result, mysql_fetch_row, etc.) with the "mysqli" version?  Is it as easy as a global search and replace with "mysqli"?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. However you should probably switch anyway, as "mysql" driver is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will removed "in the future". [See the manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)